# Using LiveData in data binding instead of MutableLiveData

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, mutablelivedata, android-livedata

Hi I am using LiveData instead of MutableLiveData because I am getting LiveData from Room and it is working even after removing `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);`. My question, is there any problem with that? Hope it helps to others

Comment: Question isn't clear, What you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not going to set a `LifecycleOwner`, then you might as well not use `LiveData`.

One of the biggest benefits of using `LiveData`, especially with `Room` and `DataBinding` is the ability for it to be lifecycle aware and have the values observed. Which means it'll be able to automatically update your Views with the latest updated data.

According to [official documentations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#setLifecycleOwner(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner)): `setLifecycleOwner()` is used for a `LiveData` to be able to observe changes, such as from `Room`. If there's no `LifecycleOwner` set, then the `LiveData` won't be observed and no updates will be sent to your UI through Databinding.

For a quick test, I've commented out the `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)` in one of my Activities. The results proved the documentations are true. My UI was no longer getting changes from my `LiveData` objects.